# Appending values to a slice on an np array

Tags: python, append, slice

I have an numpy array which I have initialized and looks like this:

```
pulse = np.ndarray(shape = (300, 10001, 3), dtype = float)
```

I want to fill this array with some data I am reading from a file. 
An example of the way I want to fill it looks like this:

```
pulse[0][0][0] = 1
pulse[0][1:10001][0] = data
```

where data is an array of 10000 elements.

Could this be done using append or another function of numpy?

Comment: Also I'd recommend u to check https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

Comment: @yatu Thank you for the recommendation! I will have a better look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you're current approach is that you're *assigning to a copy* of the data, and hence the original array remains unchanged. Instead assign to a view of the array (which is known as *slice assignment*), this way you'll be modifying in-place:

```
pulse[0, 1:10001, 0] = data
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
pulse[0,0,0]= 1
pulse[0,1:1001,0]= data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pulse[0][0][0] = 1
pulse[0][1:10001][0] = data
```

this will work. the dimension of data must be exactly the size of the slice. Also instead of assigning an array, if you assign a constant, all the elements in the slice will be assigned that value.